# HTTP Response body type in RAML for an API

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, raml, apikit

I am creating an API with Mule Anypoint Design center, where I receive data with type text/plain from other endpoints. Can I just use text/plain in below raml code instead of application/json?

Why am I asking this?

My endpoint is AWS SNS and it sends, a HTTP header, Content-Type, with value  "text/plain" only and the apikit router in studio validates whether the content-type is "whatever specified in RAML spec(application/json)". Ofcourse I can disable validations, but I have other things to validate which depends on it.

```
responses: 
  201:
    body: 
      application/json:
        example:  {"msg" : "Flight inserted successfully"}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2023, Amazon SNS now supports custom `Content-Type` headers for HTTP messages delivered from topics. Here's the announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-sns-content-type-request-headers-http-s-notifications/

You simply have to modify the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute of your Amazon SNS subscription, setting the `headerContentType` property to `application/json`, `application/xml`, or any other value supported. You can find all values supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy

```
{
    "healthyRetryPolicy": {
        "minDelayTarget": 1,
        "maxDelayTarget": 60,
        "numRetries": 50,
        "numNoDelayRetries": 3,
        "numMinDelayRetries": 2,
        "numMaxDelayRetries": 35,
        "backoffFunction": "exponential"
    },
    "throttlePolicy": {
        "maxReceivesPerSecond": 10
    },
    "requestPolicy": {
        "headerContentType": "application/json"
    }
}
```

You set the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute by calling either the `Subscribe` or the `SetSubscriptionAttributes` API action:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetSubscriptionAttributes.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change it to text/plain in RAML if needed. But if you want your response to be json, you'd be better off transforming your payload and overwriting the Content-type header in Mule/Anypoint design center.

Comment: But in design-center, we have just 4 options application/json, application/xml, form type and multipart data. Will text/plain work. If yes, please point to a resource of the kind.

Comment: yes it does. the ui doesn't offer every possible media type, so just type it explicitly